# Can't get data from my db into swig template

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a project and can't figure out why I can't get the data that is present (when I console.log) Into my view. Here is my Route File:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var models = require('../models');



router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  models.Destination.find(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results); // THIS HAS ALL MY DATA
    res.render('index', { destination: results, title: "Practice App" });

    });
});

module.exports = router;

Here is my index.html view file:

{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>Welcome to {{title}}</p>
    <h1>{{destination}}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately when I run this with {{destination}}, my app crashes.  If I take out {{destination}}, {{title}} will work, which is just a string I am passing to render in

```
res.render('index', { destination: results, title: "Practice App" })
```

Why can't I get access to the value of results coming from my db even though when I console.log a line above I have all the data?

Comment: Are there are error messages emitted when your app crashes?  Including them would be helpful in debugging your issue.

Comment: Is 'results' an array? I don't have much experience with swig, but from its documentation, it uses a 'for..in' loop to print values in an array. It might be a possible issue if you are directly asking it to print the array.